# cannot separate dollars and cents python

Tags: python

This function now works but the problem I am now having is separating the dollars from cents. It keeps giving me the same dollars as left_over_cents. How can I just show the cents?

```
def main():
    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies  : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels  : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes    : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies   : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels   : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes     : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters  : " , quarters)

    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

    print("Total = $",format(total_value, ".2f"), sep="")
    print("You have", dollars, "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)")

def get_input(message):
    get_input = int(input(message))
    while get_input <= 0:
        print("Error")
        get_input = int(input(message))
    return get_input

def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    pennies = (.01 * pennies);
    nickels = .05 * nickels;
    dimes = .10 * dimes;
    quarters = .25 * quarters;
    total_value = pennies + nickels + dimes + quarters
    return total_value

def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = format(total_value // 1, ".0f")
    return dollars

def get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total_value = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = total_value % 1
    return left_over_cents

main()
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve the problem?

Comment: Of course they're the same. Your `get_left_over_cents` function simply calls `get_dollars` and returns the result. If you want different values, you need to do different things.

Comment: How would I be able to use the "total_value % 1"?

Comment: You could move the string formatting from `get_dollars` to `main` (so `get_dollars` returns a number - instead of a string - which will be compatible with `%`).

Comment: could you show what you mean exactly?

Answer (score -1):

You want to remove the dollars from the total value, for instance by something like

```
total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
left_over_cents = total_value % 1
```

(`% 1` gives the remainder after dividing by 1)

Comment: `get_dollars` is currently returning a string, so this will throw a TypeError exception.